# what is the difference between wcf service and web service?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Web Service vs WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351334/web-service-vs-wcf-service)

Duplicate:

[Web Service vs WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351334/web-service-vs-wcf-service)

---

What is the difference between WCF service and Webservice ?

Comment: WCF is a .NET 3.5 technology introduced by Microsoft. It unifies all communication options available in earlier versions of .NET framework. You can make a WCF application that would act exactly the same as a WebService, but it will be easier to implement and manage. See [Getting Started with Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx) for more details.

Comment: This link could be helpful http://www.dotnettechy.com/articles/whats-the-difference-between-wcf-and-web-services-301.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

WCF is a programming model and API.
"WCF Service" implies an app that is built using that programming model and API.

"Web Service" is an app that exposes an HTTP (REST (XML or JSON), SOAP or otherwise) interface.

You can build a Web service using WCF, but you can also build a Web service using other APIs or "stacks".  Like PHP or Java, for example.

With WCF you can build web services but you can also build services that are not, "Webbish".  For example you can build a service that accepts incoming binary requests over only a local pipe interface.  It is still a service, but it is not a "web service" because it is not using web protocols (generally HTTP and XML).

Answer (score 5):

WCF is an extension - it's a web service, but you can expose it over TCP/IP, or named pipes, in addition to just using HTTP.

Also, WCF has lots more options for security and so on.

You can also host a WCF service inside your own app - you don't have to use IIS for hosting the web service (ASMX).

In conclusion: WCF *IS* web services - just much more flexible and much more useful than straight ASMX web services.

Marc

Answer (score 1):

I think these two links will give you all the information you need :

[Comparing ASP.NET Web Services to WCF Based on Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738737.aspx)

[Comparing ASP.NET Web Services to WCF Based on Purpose and Standards Used](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702755.aspx)

Also, check this question :
[What is difference with WCF and other web services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412698/what-is-difference-with-wcf-and-other-web-services)