# webservice vs wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, asmx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is difference with WCF and other web services ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412698/what-is-difference-with-wcf-and-other-web-services)

What are the main difference  between web service and wcf service ?
how to call both service?

Comment: Generally: WCF service is web service.

Comment: Please search for [wcf][asmx] and you'll find many answers telling you the same thing: ASMX web services have been replaced by WCF.

Comment: People, please don't answer this duplicate question.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka - I could not disagree more. WCF can do everything a web service can do, but also much much more. Like in-process communication, use different protocols. Built in functionality for reliability, security, sessions and so on and so on...

Comment: @Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen: I posted it before John added ASMX tag. If we talk about Web service as is (not about ASMX implementation) the statement is valid.

Answer (score 1):

This is a big question, but a WCF service is much more versatile and can do what a web service can do and much more. See [this](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/17319/57647.aspx) post for more detailed information regarding this issue.